# According to this table, can I say my variables are integrated of order 1?

Tags: unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I tested my variables in ADF unit root test , can I say they all integrated in order of 1?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reject the null hypothesis of a unit root in levels for either of the three specifications, using conventional significance levels of 1%, 5% or 10%.
You can reject the null hypothesis of a unit root in first differences for all three specifications, using conventional significance levels of 5% or 10%.*
If you believe that at least one of the specifications is adequate for your time series, then **yes**, you can conclude your time series is integrated of order 1.

* 1% might not work out since you have multiple hypothesis being tested in this table, so you have to adjust the significance level for that. However, if you chose to ignore two out of three specifications altogether before seeing the test results and hence look only at the one in red, then 1% is also fine.